# hiding a google visualization column with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a JavaScript web tool using Google Visualization API. One of the features I would like to have is the option of clicking in a column, and having a **yes** - **no** option. When **yes** is selected, then that particular column would be hidden.
I added this listener, and this function to hide the column:

```
    /* Define a table */
    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'Table',
      'containerId': 'chart2',
      'options': {
        'sortColumn': '-1',
        'allowHtml' : 'true',
      },
      'style' : {
            'white-space' : 'nowrap'
      }
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select',
            function (){
                var tablewrapper = table.getChart();
                //var columnId = tablewrapper.getColumnDescriptions();
                //console.log(tablewrapper);
                /*var columnIndex = tablewrapper.getViewColumnIndex(); */
                var selection = tablewrapper.getSelection();
                for(var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++){
                    var item = selection[i];
                    console.log('{row:' + item.row + ',column:' + item.column + '}');
                }

            }
    );

function hideColumn(columnIndex){
        $('#chart2 td:nth-child(' + (columnIndex+1) + ')').hide(); 
        return;
      }
```

However, `ev` does not have a property called `column`, which may refer to the column index. Does someone know how can I do that trick, and if I'm missing something?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<s>Maybe you're in need of a [Dataview](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView)? You can use the [hideColums()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView_hideColumns) method to hide specified columns.</s>

> A read-only view of an underlying DataTable. A DataView allows
>   selection of only a subset of the columns and/or rows. It also allows
>   reordering columns/rows, and duplicating columns/rows.
>
> A view is a live window on the underlying DataTable...

**EDIT**
[getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#visgetselection) would be a better fit to your question I guess.

Comment: RobIII, my script to hide the column works great. I just need to figure out how to get the `columnIndex`.

Comment: I noticed I missed some info on your post. My bad. Did you take a look at the `ev` variable in a debugger to see what it contains? Just a wild guess; don't you need [getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#visgetselection)?

Comment: How can I output `ev` in other to see what it contains?

Comment: Well, in Chrome and IE (and AFAIK Firefox too) `console.log(ev);` will do the trick. Then in your console window you should (in Chrome at least) be able to drill into the object. It's been a while since I was in other browsers than Chrome, so for Firefox you might need Firebug. In IE F12 should open the "developer tools". In Chrome it's CTRL+SHIFT+j. Also, did you see my [getSelection()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530964/hiding-a-google-visualization-column-with-javascript/11531276#comment15244611_11531276) suggestion?

Comment: `ev` is empty. However, doing `var tablewrapper = table.getChart();` I'm able to take the `table` object. From now on, do you know how to get the `columnIndex`?

Comment: Again; did you take a look at [my getSelection()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530964/hiding-a-google-visualization-column-with-javascript/11531276#comment15244611_11531276) suggestion? As far as I understand the documentation it should return the selection from the visualisztion (being either a row (column==null), column (row==null) or cell (row and column neither null).

Comment: `{row:0,column:undefined}`, and I don't need the `row` object.

Comment: That would indicate you selected a row (possibly the (table?) header?). On what kind of chart/visualisation is the listener used? Isn't `table` the datatable? [Shouldn't you pass the visualisation to `addListener()`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events#Event_Listeners)? I'm just guessing here...

Comment: That's indication when I click over the cell `(0, 0)` of my table it returned me `{row:0,column:undefined}` (does not display the `column:0` which I need.

Comment: Maybe [this sample](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#select_event) can help you out?

Comment: If you run the code, and click in a table cell, you will see it executes the second condition (`else if`), which means `column` is null.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out why `column` is null.

Comment: Not all visualizations might support all the types (row, column, cell) of selections. Could you post an example of your visualization on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something? That would make it easier for us to see what's going on.

Comment: I updated my question ... my visualization utilized a `MySQL` database to get it's information, so it would be useless ...

Comment: I don't see how MySQL (being the backend) has to do with the visualisation other than being a (server-side) datesource? How is this relevant or would it make any information here useless? Also, I don't see how your updated question would reflect that fact?

Comment: It doesn't work (404 when I click "new entry"). Also, you might want to trim it down (to make it more comprehensible) to only, and just, the code needed to reproduce your problem. Make a dummy table and populate it with a few rows/columns and then reproduce the getSelection() problem you're having. Leave out stuff like "category picker control for the Gender column" since it has nothing to do with your actual problem.